# Mercurial: Any ideas on how to skip some changesets when merging between branches?

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging

Here our situation:
We have two branches in our Mercurial repository lets call them Branch A and Branch B.

- Branch A is for the stable version of the code
- Branch B is for the development branch

Everything that was modified in branch A has been merged to branch B.
However now we came to a point where the code in branch B has several differences from branch A.
We made some large code changes in branch A, merging these changes in branch B would be a real pain and actually we would like to make an alternative implementation of the solution.
However later we would also like to continue the changes on branch A and still be able to merge these later minor changes into branch B.
So the question is:
Is it possible to skip some single changesets from branch A when merging into branch B and merge later changesets from A into B again? (Possibly with a pure Hg solution and no workarounds, with copies from backups and so on...)

Here an overview of what we would reach:

```
    Changesets Branch A     Changesets Branch B
    Chgset A.1              Chgset B.1 (Merged with A.1)
    Chgset A.2
                            Chgset B.2 (**Not merged with A.2**)
    Chgset A.3              Chgset B.3 (Merged with A.3 but not with A.2)
```

Thanks in advance for any advices

Comment: What you're looking to do is called *cherrypicking*.  You should do as @shellholic suggests below, but in general you can avoid having to do this entirely by being more careful about the parentage of your changesets when you first create them.  If a change will need to go from one branch to another make sure it's parent changeset is a changeset that will be going over too.  In your example A.3's parent should have been A.1 not A.2, Then you could just `hg pull -r A.3` and get it but not A.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the exact purpose of the [`transplant`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) extension.

The `transplant` extension (cherry-picking in other DVCS) keep tracks of what comes from where when you copy change sets, so merge is easier.

You have to activate the extension first (it is *included* but disabled *by default*). In your `hgrc` file, add:

```
[extensions]
transplant=
```

Comment: Just discovered that stackoverflow doesn't merge well... :-p

Comment: Since Mercurial 2.0 there is a new core command `graft` which does this.